# Can "feel oneself" ever be grammatical?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can "feel oneself" ever be grammatical (as opposed to just "feel")? Could it just be a bad translation from German? All Quiet On The Western Front

> We stick out our chests, shave in the open, shove our hands in our pockets, inspect the recruits and **feel ourselves** stone-age veterans.

> I sit up, I **feel myself** strangely alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatical, with two possible meanings.

The first meaning is literally to feel yourself, like to touch your body.

The second meaning is to believe that you are something. In this context, it means:

> We **believe we are** stone-age veterans.

Comment: Also, "It's hard to feel oneself when away from home" or similar constructions — the sense used in "I don't feel quite myself today." To feel at ease, to feel as one normally does...

Comment: And you could construct sentences with these words as an accidental collocation: "I'm the one who would benefit, and I don't feel myself that it's worthwhile." (A less likely order than "I myself don't feel", but not impossible.)

Comment: Check this one out, "I sit up, I feel myself strangely alone". That is certainly bad translation from German